# Not being able to manipulate the Resolution or FrameRate in UWP/Win IOT Application

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working on a win IOT application using the Camera Resolution Sample to try to configure my Microsoft Life Cam-3000 to a custom Res/FPS for my win IOT application on the **raspberry pi 3**.

The current FPS/Resolution that my raspberry pi 3 is set to when i plug the camera in to the pi and initiate the camera to preview the fed lags really bad and it glitches. Any suggestions or ideas? I tried to initially set the FPS and calculate it on my own but i get this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll Attempted to read or write
>   protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is
>   corrupt.

Any suggestions or ideas? I'm kind of at my wits end trying to configure this camera through the backend.

Here is my code to initiate the camera.

```
 public class MediaCapturePreviewer
{
    CoreDispatcher _dispatcher;
    CaptureElement _previewControl;

    public MediaCapturePreviewer(CaptureElement previewControl, CoreDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        _previewControl = previewControl;
        _dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public bool IsPreviewing { get; private set; }
    public bool IsRecording { get; set; }
    public MediaCapture MediaCapture { get; private set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the MediaCapture, starts preview.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
    {
        MediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
       // MediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;

        try
        {
            await MediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
            _previewControl.Source = MediaCapture;
            await MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            IsPreviewing = true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // This can happen if access to the camera has been revoked.
            // MainPage.Current.NotifyUser("The app was denied access to the camera", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            await CleanupCameraAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task CleanupCameraAsync()
    {
        if (IsRecording)
        {
            await MediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();
            IsRecording = false;
        }

        if (IsPreviewing)
        {
            await MediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
            IsPreviewing = false;
        }

        _previewControl.Source = null;

        if (MediaCapture != null)
        {
            MediaCapture.Dispose();
            MediaCapture = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is from the sample project from microsoft github  via this link. -> https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution

I looked at microsoft documentation as well via this link  -> 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/set-media-encoding-properties

Now, there's a class called StreamResolution in that project mentioned above ^ that is used to configure the FPS/Res of a camera. which is my end goal.

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper class around IMediaEncodingProperties to help how devices report supported resolutions
/// </summary>
public class StreamResolution
{
     IMediaEncodingProperties _properties;


    public StreamResolution(IMediaEncodingProperties properties)
    {
        if (properties == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(properties));
        }

        // Only handle ImageEncodingProperties and VideoEncodingProperties, which are the two types that GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties can return
        if (!(properties is ImageEncodingProperties) && !(properties is VideoEncodingProperties))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument is of the wrong type. Required: " + typeof(ImageEncodingProperties).Name
                + " or " + typeof(VideoEncodingProperties).Name + ".", nameof(properties));
        }

        // Store the actual instance of the IMediaEncodingProperties for setting them later
        _properties = properties;
    }

    public uint Width
    {
        get
        {
            if (_properties is ImageEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as ImageEncodingProperties).Width;
            }
            else if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).Width=352;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {

                (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).Width = 352;
            }

        }
    }

    public uint Height
    {
        get
        {
            if (_properties is ImageEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as ImageEncodingProperties).Height;
            }
            else if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).Height = 288;
            }

            return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {

                (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).Height = 288;
            }
        }
    }


    public uint FrameRate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {
                if ((_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Denominator != 0)
                {
                    return (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Numerator / (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Denominator;
                }
```

}

```
            return 0;
        }

        //set { (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).Bitrate = 1 / 10; }


    }

public double AspectRatio
    {
        get { return Math.Round((Height != 0) ? (Width / (double)Height) : double.NaN, 2); }
    }

    public IMediaEncodingProperties EncodingProperties
    {
        get { return _properties; }
        set => EncodingProperties = _properties;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Output properties to a readable format for UI purposes
    /// eg. 1920x1080 [1.78] 30fps MPEG
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Readable string</returns>
    public string GetFriendlyName(bool showFrameRate = true)
    {
        if (_properties is ImageEncodingProperties ||
            !showFrameRate)
        {
            return Width + "x" + Height + " [" + AspectRatio + "] " + _properties.Subtype;
        }
        else if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
        {
            return Width + "x" + Height + " [" + AspectRatio + "] " + FrameCalc + "FPS" + _properties.Subtype;
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

when i tried to edit the FPS it gives me the unhandled exception after i use this to set the media stream properties right after i initiate the camera.

```
            await _previewer.MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, streamResolution.EncodingProperties);
```

update: when i looked a bit deeper into my issue i found this. -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaproperties.videoencodingproperties

the video encoding properties class it said the frame rate data can be get but not set? but it initially says in the documentation that it can be set but no set property for the Frame rate?!

Comment: Without your code to refer to, that exception doesn't help much.

Comment: Thanks, I will add it.

Comment: I test [the CameraResolution sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution) on Raspberry Pi 3 with version 10.0.15063.0, it works. What's your OS version?

Comment: my OS verison is the latest @RitaHan-MSFT my end goal is manipulating the FPS or the Res-Width/Height. I made a MSDN Article and i will attach a video hopefully i'm not confusing anyone. -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsapps/en-US/b51644d3-07d3-484f-96d6-bbc58e254264/not-being-able-to-manipulate-the-resolution-or-framerate-in-uwpwin-iot-application?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT here is a video explaining my issue. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M4ciBZKorKFF5IRH0LXSUG7IHzhEJZoc after, you see that video i used the camera resolution sample project to figure out why the camera wouldn't stop glitching then i figured out it was the FPS. when i tried to set my own custom FPS before the feed initiates that's when i got the "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: Yes, the FrameRate can't be set. There is a mismatch between document and API implementation. I find that there are 7/10/15/20/30 frame rates can be selected through preview settings in camera resolution sample. Have you tried all of them? Any help?

Comment: I did @RitaHan-MSFT however, to solve my issue i have to somehow pre-set the camera resolution and FPS before the camera initiates? any ideas/suggestions! or maybe i can use that sample to make the settings somehow global i'm not sure i'm thinking on the top of my head at the moment. however, you the only one i see who understands what my issue is so far.

Comment: I did more test, on Minnowboard, there is no glitching no matter what frame rate and video format, but on raspberry pi the glitching is very bad. Meanwhile, the CPU utilization is nearly 100%. Finally, I found that "160x120 [1.33] 7FPS YUY2" receive the much better result on raspberry pi so you can have a try. The frame rate can be set is from device and driver supported list so you may not customize this value by yourself except you can config the camera setting. You can check [this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera-profiles)

Comment: Hi, @RitaHan-MSFT please look at this link here i have another guy from MSFT team helping out as well i will be posting most recent responses here. -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b51644d3-07d3-484f-96d6-bbc58e254264/not-being-able-to-manipulate-the-resolution-or-framerate-in-uwpwin-iot-application?forum=WindowsIoT&ppud=4